# ffmpeg output error of YouTube videos in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not trying to download the whole video, just 5 seconds of a video. I tried following this [guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command). However, this is for in line command and I'm trying to do this with python code. So far I've managed to extract all the required information using youtube-dl. The problem I'm having now is using ffmpeg to output the video with the given parameters, but it's saying it cannot find the file specified.

This is what I have so far:

```
import youtube_dl
import datetime
import ffmpeg
def getInfo():
    link='https://youtu.be/nda20uSjQUI?t=11981'
    ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})

    #This exctracts all the information of the link
    with ydl:
        result = ydl.extract_info(
            link,
            download=False
        )
    #Grabs the duration of the video
        duration_info = result.get('duration')
    #Grabs the url to the actual video file
        url = str(result).split("'url':",1)[1].split(', ')[0]

    #YouTube(link).streams.first().download('D:/Downloads')
    #Determines the start time based on how the link is formatted
    #They can be in three possible formats
    if 't=' in link:
        if link.endswith('s'):
            time_seconds = link.split('t=', 1)[1].strip('s')
        else:
            time_seconds = link.split('t=', 1)[1]
    else:
        time_seconds = '0'

    #Converts the time into an HH:MM:ss format
    #We only want 5 seconds of video, which is what timestamp_end does
    timestamp_start = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(time_seconds)))
    timestamp_end = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(time_seconds)+5))
    video_length = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(duration_info)))

    #If the segment we want is less than 5 seconds, such as towards the end of the video,
    #then the end will be the end of the actual video
    if timestamp_end > video_length:
        timestamp_end = video_length

    #Returns a list of [url, start, end]
    return url ,timestamp_start,timestamp_end

def download_video(result):
    #Checks to see if there's a valid argument
    if result is None:
        return 'Error: no url found'
    else:
        file_input = ffmpeg.input(result[0])
        out = ffmpeg.concat(file_input.trim(start_frame=result[1],end_frame=result[2])).output('test1.mp4').run()
        return out

download_video(result=getInfo())
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anonymous/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 53, in <module>
    download_video(result=getInfo())
  File "C:/Users/Anonymous/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 50, in download_video
    out = ffmpeg.concat(file_input.trim(start_frame=result[1],end_frame=result[2])).output('test1.mp4').run()
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 320, in run
    overwrite_output=overwrite_output,
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 285, in run_async
    args, stdin=stdin_stream, stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and be very specific about what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg installed?

Comment: @Rishav yes I have ffmpeg installed.